# Proving that every connected graph of order 4 that is not $K_{1,3}$ has a perfect matching.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-writing, matching-theory

I am asked to prove two things:

(a) Prove that every connected graph of order 4 that is not $K_{1,3}$ has a perfect matching.

(b) Let G be a connected graph of even order. Prove that if G contains no induced subgraph isomorphic to $K_{1,3}$, then G has a perfect matching.

Now, I think that proving part a might help a lot with part b but I am not too sure how to approach this. I have seen a solution around mentioning something about claws but I have not learned that so I do not get it. I do see I would need to find a set that contains 2 edges to have a perfect matching since the order is 4 but I am not sure how to continue. Any suggestions?

Comment: There aren't that many connected graphs of order $4$. Why not just check them all?

Comment: @Arthur I know. There are 5 others besides $K_{1,3}$, which I did draw out so I know it’s true but it asks to prove this and I’m not sure how to.

Comment: @Sam  Those five examples would constitute a proof, provided you prove they are the only connected graphs of order 4 other than $K_{1,3}$

Comment: @saulspatz I am not sure how just giving examples of all 5 graphs constitutes as a proof.

Comment: You give the five graphs, and exhibit the complete matching for each.  You need to explain why these are all the possible graphs, though.  If you're taking an introductory course in discrete math, or something like that, this is probably the proof your instructor has in mind.

Comment: Yes, this is an introductory course so we haven’t gotten into a lot of the bigger theorems but we have done quite a few. Okay, well would it be sufficient to say these 5 are the only ones that work because the others are disconnected?

Answer (score 2):

Assume for a contradiction that $G$ is a connected graph of order $4$ which is not $K_{1,3}$ and has no perfect matching.

$G$ is a spanning subgraph of the graph $K_4,$ which has a proper edge-coloring with $3$ colors. Since $G$ has no perfect matching, it has at most one edge of each color; therefore, $G$ has at most $3$ edges.

Since $G$ is connected of order $4,$ it has at least $3$ edges. Therefore $G$ is a tree and has exactly $3$ edges.

Plainly, $G$ has no vertex of degree greater than $3.$ Moreover, since $G$ is not $K_{1,3},$ it has no vertex of degree $3.$ Therefore $G$ has maximum degree at most $2.$

A tree with maximum degree $\le2$ is a path. Therefore $G=P_4.$ But $P_4,$ a path of even order, has a perfect matching. This contradicts our assumption that $G$ has no perfect matching.

Comment: Sorry to ask but what do you mean by coloring? I have not learned that yet.

Comment: The edges of $K_4$ can be colored with three colors so that no two edges of the same color have a common vertex. Namely, if the vertices are $a,b,c,d,$ you can color the edges $ab$ and $cd$ red, color $ac$ and $bd$ white, and color $ad$ and $bc$ blue. Now two edges of the same color will be a perfect matching of $K_4.$ Therefore, if a subgraph $G$ of $K_4$ has no perfect matching, then it contains at most one edge of each color. $G$ can have at most one red edge, at most one white edge, and at most one blue edge, so at most $3$ edges all told.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand coloring a bit more. Is there anyway to do this proof without the coloring aspect? Isn’t this just the same as saying we are finding a perfect match in the graph?

Comment: Sure. The complete graph with vertices $a,b,c,d$ has $6$ edges; they are $ab,ac,ad,bc,bc,cd.$ A subgraph with no complete matching can contain at most one of $ab,cd$ and at most one of $ac,bd$ and at most one of $ad,bc.$  Expressing the argument in terms of edge colorings is just a way to make the exposition shorter and easier for someone who already knows about edge colorings.

Comment: Okay, I am sorry I did not mention I do not know anything about edge colorings, which is why your answer did not make sense to me.

Comment: So, you are basing your answer on the complete graph on 4 vertices and finding perfect matching from there?

Answer (score 2):

A $3$-edge path has a perfect matching (shown in red):

[image]

A connected $4$-vertex graph has a spanning tree: either $K_{1,3}$ or a $3$-edge path (as there are no other $4$-vertex trees).

If we add an edge to $K_{1,3}$, we get a $3$-edge-path subgraph (and thus a perfect matching):

[image]

Thus, except for $K_{1,3}$, any connected $4$-vertex graph has a $3$-edge subgraph, and thus a perfect matching.